# Gmail API - Send URL with parameters in HTML content

Tags: php, gmail, base64, gmail-api

I'm trying to send mails via GMAIL API.

Here's my code :

```
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
$header = "From: ".$fromName."<".$this->emailUser.">\r\n";
$header .= "To:".$toName." <".$dossierEmail.">\r\n";
$header .= 'Subject: =?utf-8?B?' . $subject . "?=\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$header .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' . "\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $message . "\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";

foreach ($attachments as $attachment) 
        {
            $file = $attachment['path'].$attachment['filename'];
            $file_size = filesize($file);
            $handle = fopen($file, "r");
            $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
            fclose($handle);
            $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
            //$mimeTypeFile = $this->getMimeType( $attachment['type'] );

$header .= "Content-Type: ".$attachment['mimetype']."; name=\"".$attachment['filename']."\"\r\n"; 
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$attachment['filename']."\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
        }

$mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($header), '+/', '-_'), '=');

$msg = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
$msg->setRaw($mime);
```

This code is OK, i'm sending mail BUT the problem is that when i'm sending URL with parameters such as :

```
https://www.myadress.com/blabla?rel=0&data=ok
```

It will send:

```
https://www.myadress.com/blabla?rel0&dataok
```

I guess its because of the base64 thing ... so how can I send this type of URL ?

Comment: Can you specify  what Gmail method you're using and where does this URL exactly go, what is the expected outcome?

Comment: Changing "quoted-printable" to "base64" resolved my issue. Thanks.